# Final Mat_Lab Project

Tags: matlab

I am working on a final Mat_Lab project and while I have the code written I am having an issue where it won't graph an imported data.
the first two parts are as follow:

```
%parte 1 abre el archivo:
Data = readtable('Proyecto_Final.xlsx');
opts = 'skip Ln1';
```

%parte 2 graficas lineales:

```
   hold on;
    figure(1);
    x=Data(:, 1);
    y=Data(:, 2:11);
    plot(x,y,'m*:');
    xlabel('Time(s)');
    ylabel("Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5", "Day 6", "Day 7", "Day 8", "Day 9", "Day 10");
   hold off;
```

The data in question comes from an Excell file and the following mistakes come through:

Error using tabular/plot (line 217)
Tables and timetables do not have a plot method. To plot a table or a timetable, use the stackedplot function. As an
alternative, extract table or timetable variables using dot or brace subscripting, and then pass the variables as input
arguments to the plot function.

Error in ProyectoFinal (line 17)

```
plot(x,y,'m*:');
```

Which I did added under the ylabel as `stackedplot (x,y);`

Comment: Please, provide a minimally reproducible example. It is hard to understand what is wrong if we cannot run the code.

Comment: Does your xlsx file have a header row ie does every column has its name?

Comment: @Imran, yes it does but the first instruction requires us to ignore it using commands which is why I am using the ops= 'skip Line 1';

Comment: @nonDucor apologize, I am using an Excell file with a matrix of 30x11 where the first column is the x data and the y label are the other 10 columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a column of a MATLAB table by the command `Data(:, 1)`, rather you should use `Data.Var1` where Var1 is the name of the column.

Using the following `test.txt` file an MWE (minimum workable example) is provided. Edit this as per your table:

```
test.txt

1 12 12 47
2 24 19 32
4 45 48 31  
5 54 12 27 
6 68 95 56
7 82 45 56
8 94 36 56
9 102 12 24
```

MWE:

```
Data = readtable('test.txt');

hold on;
    figure(1);
    x = Data.Var1
    y = [Data.Var2, Data.Var3, Data.Var4];
    plot(x,y,'m*:');
    xlabel('Time(s)');
    ylabel("Day data")
    legend("Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3");
   hold off;
```

Output plot:

[image]

**Note:** I think with the command `\ylabel`, you are actually trying to produce legends. See the corresponding documentation ([ylabel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylabel.html) and [legend](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will update it and keep coming back, the next parts are about if the user wishes they can use different graphs and more, but your answer helped me in the first bit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issues pertaining the project, I stayed all night up until 6am going back and forth a Discord server called matlab, project ran well and was successfully submitted. Thanks for all the help, here is how it was solved:

[image: Project part 1]

[image: Project part 2]

[image: Project part 3]

[image: Project part 4]

[image: Project part 5]

[image: figure (1)]

[image: graph selection]

[image: figure (2)]

[image: figure (3)]

[image: Project part 6]

[image: Project Data]

Thanks again for your help and pointers, may these images help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.